# MyQNAP Cloud security

Tags: cloud-computing, openvpn

I recently set up my new QNAP NAS, and have been accessing it through OpenVPN running on my Raspberry Pi through my home network.

For convenience, I decided to test out MyQNAPCloud, which puts it online.

I've got the SSL certs with it, but the login page isn't HTTPS (it is only after you have logged in) and I'm not too sure about having more ports open to the internet, instead of just 1194 for OpenVPN.

EDIT:

I'll rephrase the above. Is there a way to make the MyQNAPCloud more secure other than the obvious disabling services / not have it internet facing?

It opens up a number of ports to the internet, depending on what services are running. When closing it down to go back to the Raspberry Pi VPN and keeping everything on the local network, I found that MyQNAPCloud allowed access to my router through the internet. I'm no pentester, but I'm guessing that would be a potential avenue to go down for an attacker and pivot from there to other devices?